# Function call in R with named parameters - the name is in a variable instead of writing it directly in the function call

Tags: r, function, parameters

Suppose I have this function:

```
f <- function(a = 0, b = 1) {
    ...
}
```

I want to call this function and specify only parameter **b**:

```
f(b = 2);
```

However, instead of writing **b** directly above, I would like, if possible, to have the parameter name in a variable:

```
temp = "b";
f(temp = 2);
```

The above attempt obviously does not work in R. Any way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: In practice I have a function with about 20 parameters, and only those specified in a configuration file will be added to the function call, and the remaining ones will take default values.

So, let's say, out of 20 different values, there are 5 pairs (parameter name, value) in a configuration file, and I need to invoke a function with those 5 parameters.

Comment: You probably want `do.call()`.  For this it's `do.call(f, setNames(list(2), temp))`